# ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers Windows Delete/Rename OneDrive Keys

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-registry

I'm currently dealing with `ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` in Windows, where I'm trying to delete (or rename) some `OneDrive` keys in the registry. I'm using Windows 10 64-Bit, admin account. Since only a few number of such `ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` are possible at the same time on Windows, I want to delete the `OneDrive` keys (or at least rename them with e.g. a "z" prefix to appear at the end) to make e.g. my `DropBox` icons showing up again.

I navigated to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`. Deleting/Renaming e.g. a `Tortoise` key is not a problem at all, but only the `OneDrive` keys causing trouble.

Acutally, when I tried to delete/rename them, an error message showed up: `OneDriveX cannot be deleted. Failure while trying to delete the key.` Note that this is my translation of the error message and that X has to be replaced by the actual number.

I also tried to right click on such a key -> permissions to give me full access. But when I click on OK, an error message shows up like: `The permission information for OneDriveX has not been saved. Access denied`.

Does anyone know how to get rid of those OneDrive keys or already had the same problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: stop the running Onedrive.exe first

Comment: @magicandre1981 - Doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is somewhat tedious, but you can do it like this:

1. Obtain ownership of each key by right clicking it, then clicking "Advanced", the "Change" near Owner: TrustedInstaller - use "Administrators"
2. Give "Administrators" "Full access"
3. Delete key